# How to start checking from specific part of a list in python

Tags: python, list, arraylist

Given the list below:

```
#123
*21
*23
*56
*1
*3
#923
*21
*23
*56
*1
*3
#165
...
```

I want to find first the specific line with #

For example: #923

And then print all the numbers prefixed with * until the next occurrence of a line starting with #.

This is what I tried but it doesn't work:

```
for i in data:
     ndata = i.split("::")
     check = list(ndata[0])
     if check[0] == '*':
        songs += ndata[0] + "\n"
     if check[0] == '#':
        break
```

It does print the * and breaks on lines starting with # but the problem is that it's starting from the first line and not from the one containing #923.

I will appreciate any help and tips!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `itertools.dropwhile`  to drop lines until you get to the line you want then loop until you get a line starting with `#`

```
from itertools import dropwhile   
def section(fle, start, stop):
    with open(fle) as f:
        # consume lines until we get to our start line
        drop = dropwhile(lambda x: x.strip() != start, f)
        # skip start
        next(drop, "")
        # loop starting at line after start line
        for line in drop:
            # if we reach stop line break
            if line.startswith(stop):
                break
            # else we just yield the line
            yield line.rstrip()
```

Output:

```
In [4]: list(section("in.txt", "#923", "#"))
Out[4]: ['*21', '*23', '*56', '*1', '*3']
```

To work for multiple sections starting from start and delimited by lines starting with `#`:

```
from itertools import dropwhile, groupby


def section(fle, start, end):
    with open(fle) as f:
        grps = groupby(dropwhile(lambda x: x.strip() != start, f),
                       key=lambda x: x.startswith(end))
        for k, v in grps:
            if not k:
                yield list(map(str.strip,v))
```

Demo:

```
n [13]: cat in.txt
(4.471719725275173E-003,2.163649191486555E-002)
(6.471719725275173E-003,2#123
*21
*23
*56
*1
*3
#923
*21
*23
*56
*1
*3
#165.163649191486555E-002)
*210
*230
*560
*10
*30
#165.163649191486555E-002)
In [14]: list(section("in.txt", "#923", "#"))
Out[14]: [['*21', '*23', '*56', '*1', '*3'], ['*210', '*230', '*560', '*10', '*30']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
data = ( "#123", "*21", "*23", "*56", "*1", "*3", "#923", "*21", "*23", "*56", "*1", "*3", "#16a" )

for idx,num in enumerate(data):
    if num == "#923":
        break
    #
#
for num in data[idx + 1:]:
    if num[0] == '#':
        break;
    #
    print num
#
```

Gives:

```
*21
*23
*56
*1
*3
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to make things more complicated than they are. Just use two `for` loops:

```
with open(yourFile) as fp:

    for line in fp:
        if line.startswith('#923'):
            break

    for line in fp:
        if line.startswith('#'):
            break
        if line.startswith('*'):
            print line
```

If your data is already a list, then:

```
    it = iter(yourList)

    for line in it:
        if line.startswith('#923'):
            break

    for line in it:
        if line.startswith('#'):
            break
        if line.startswith('*'):
            print line
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you do not suppress the output until you find the #923 nor do you even test for it. Thus you will pick up the first # that you find.

Notice that your for loop says `for i in data:` which includes the first line. You would need to have a flag to determine if this is first time or second time. Note that the first time you enter the loop, the first entry you test is a # entry so you will break.

What you should do (instead of break) is create a new song list and each time you get the new # entry. Append each * song to the list. Then you would have a list of the songs that go together.

Ass you have it you are treating songs as a string, you have never initialized it so the adding to the string `songs += ndata[0] = "\n` will fail.

Additionally, will the last line in the data be a # (which would create an empty songs list at the end)? If you are just adding to a string, it will exit on its own.

If you want to do a separate songs list each time, use a generator with a yield rather than a return of the songs list (or string)